# Auto switch between sentences

Tags: php, joomla

I would like my joomla site to automatically change which sentence it will echo to the user, so I wrote 3 different sentences:

```
$sentence1 = "Everything okay?";
$sentence2 = "Have a good day";
$sentence3 = "What are you doing today?";
```

I would like it to switch between the sentences, so I'm aware I can't just put `$sentence1` in the `echo` but I don't know how to write it then. I have the echo line like this:

```
echo "Hey {user->name}." . "<br />" . $sentence1
```

By the way, the `{user->name}` is from Joomla's own "codes" so that worked fine :)

Comment: `Automatically change`....when/how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

random greetings:

```
$sentence[1] = "Everything okay?";
$sentence[2] = "Have a good day";
$sentence[3] = "What are you doing today?";    

echo "Hey {user->name}." . "<br />" . $sentence[rand(1,3)]
```

Comment: Oh that was easy! :D Thank you! If I add fx 2 more sentences [4] and [5], i just change the "3" in the `echo` to 5? :)

Comment: Instead of hardcoding the maximum (3) you can use sizeof($sentence)

Comment: Fine, I just answered his comment.

Comment: @Daniel Jensen yep. change 3 to 5 or any number you need

Answer (score 1):

You could use a random function, such as `mt_rand()`:

```
$sentence1 = "Everything okay?";
$sentence2 = "Have a good day";
$sentence3 = "What are you doing today?";
$nb = mt_rand(1, 3); // Gets a random number from 1 to 3
$sentence_shown = ${'sentence' . $nb}; // Equals $sentence1, $sentence2 or $sentence3

echo "Hey {user->name}." . "<br />" . $sentence_shown;
```

Or even better, put your three strings in an array :

```
$sentences = array();
$sentences[] = "Everything okay?";
$sentences[] = "Have a good day";
$sentences[] = "What are you doing today?";
$nb = mt_rand(0, 2); // Gets a random number from 0 to 2
$sentence_shown = $sentences[$nb];

echo "Hey {user->name}." . "<br />" . $sentence_shown;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you can put your 3 sentences or 3 strings in an array, and then you can print every sentence when you loop in it. Example:

```
$array = array(sentence1, sentence2, sentence3 , ... , sentence n);
for ($index = 0; $index < sizeof($array); $index++) {
    echo 'This is sentence ' + index ':' + $array[index];
}
```

Comment: I think OP wants to echo one of the three sentences, not all three at once.